# Binding dropdown list field from Sharepoint list using C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                try
                {
                    DataTable dt = GetList();
                    ddldeedno.DataSource = dt;
                    ddldeedno.DataTextField = "DeedNo";
                    ddldeedno.DataValueField = "DeedNo";
                    ddldeedno.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.Message.ToString();
                }
            }

        }

        private DataTable GetList()
        {
            SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Land General Info");

            return list.Items.GetDataTable();

        }
```

When i use that above code its throwing an exception that "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'DeedNo'." in sharepoint 
But there is an attribute name as DeedNo in "Land General Info" list.
I don't find out any solution. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine based on my testing, make sure the filed internal name is DeedNo.

```
var list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Time");
            DataTable dt = list.Items.GetDataTable();
            ddldeedno.DataSource = dt;
            ddldeedno.DataTextField = "DeedNo";
            ddldeedno.DataValueField = "DeedNo";
            ddldeedno.DataBind();
```

[image]

[image]